# Laravel: submiting a method-delete-form fails after a wrong method-put-form validation response

Tags: forms, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have a **put-form** and a **delete-form** on the same page.

```
{{Form::open( .. 'method'=>'delete' .. )}} ... {{Form::close()}}
{{Form::open( .. 'method'=>'put' .. )}} ... {{Form::close()}}
```

When **put-form** validation fails I come back to print the errors.

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```

In that moment, if you submit a **delete-form** it becomes a **method PUT** submit !!

It is beacuse of the previous Input information stored in session ??

Mixing post/delete or put/get works fine.

There is a solutions for put/delete combination on the same page??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel sends a hidden field of `_method` for PUT and DELETE requests. Both requests are POST.

When you return to the view, you are setting the `_method` with the previously submitted `_method`.

Try changing your input for `_method` before redirecting back.

> Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field to your form.
>   [~ Laravel Docs - Opening a form](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form)

Comment: Do you mean to clean the `_method` Input on the controller right? It seems like an easy solution, till the day Laravel do it by itself.

Comment: Yup, just updated with a quote from the docs regarding PUT & DELETE